# Content behind jscrollpane div

Tags: jquery, css, scrollbar, jscrollpane

I got a pretty huge div that has a jscrollpane on it.
The div has a padding to it so the scrollbar is is displayed like 200px away from the div.
This means there is space between the div and the scrollbar. So good so far.
Now this whole thing is one a really big button.
But I can't press the button in the space between the div and the scrollbar because it's stil a part of the Jscrollpane div. The div just get's that irritating blue border around it.
Anybody know how I can make sure the big button can be clicked in that space. And if it's possible to get rid of the active state blue border?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Not sure about clicking the button, but `outline: 0` should get rid of the border.

Answer (score 0):

So the scrollpane is a button and you want it so that if the user clicks anywhere on the scrollpane then the button's action is performed?

How do you detect when somebody "presses the button"? Is the whole thing wrapped in a link? Do you use javascript to assign a click handler?

Try adding a background colour to the element which you apply jScrollPane to so that you can see it's bounds clearly. Does the button work if you press within those bounds? Is there a gap between those bounds and the scroll bar itself? If you can provide a URL showing the page setup (preferably an example put together on http://www.jsfiddle.net ) then I may be able to help a little more...

Answer (score -1):

Give a better z-index for the button

I think it might be z-index problem,

```
z-index:1000
```

Comment: Yeah but than the big button wil go over the div. And thats not something I want to achieve. There is an empty space in the div because of the padding. Normally your browser will just let you click there. But because of jscrollpane it does not. This is what I am trying to fix. So I can click on the space thats created by the padding and activate the button that is behind that div that has the padding inside of it.